# Judo gis for lanky players?

Tags: judo, gi

Lately a lot of BJJ Gi manufacturers have been making gis that are fitted for lanky players, but of those that make slim cut BJJ gis, their Judo gis are still just the standard cut (even Fushida now, surprisingly only has the standard sizes for their Judo gis).

Are there any left that make proper cuts for slimmer players?

Answer (score 3):

*@Sardathrion has a nice chart. Only it doesn't work for me. According to the chart, I should have a 180 gi, but I have a 185.*

I have a Matsuru gi and an Adidas. The Adidas is more for slim players.

I recommend an [IJF certified] [J800](http://www.adidas-judopak.com/adidas-judopak-champion-j800.html) for normal training.

[image: adidas j800 gi]

Answer (score 2):

[Nine circles](http://www.ninecircles.co.uk/) has the following chart linking weight and height of gis.  This may mean that you can get a smaller/larger gi than just your size.  I am not sure how accurate it is but the dogi I got from them always fitted.

[image]

Comment: What concerns me there is they don't have any Judo gis listed. Judo requires sleeves to be a certain length, so while a gi might fit fine and let you move as you need to, if the sleeves and pants are too short, you're SOL. Certainly can't compete and training partners won't be too happy about it either. Aikido gis go the opposite way from what I've seen, keeping the sleeves short to facilitate practicing wrist locks.

Answer (score 2):

[Adidas](https://www.combat-sports.net/en/judo/), [Mizuno](https://emea.mizuno.com/uk/en-gb/sports/other-sports/judo/), [Kappa](https://www.kappa4judo.com/collezione.html), [Fighting Films](https://fightingfilms.com/collections/kits/products/olympic-kits-ss750s?variant=39379873202225), [Essimo](https://www.essimo.co.uk/product-page/gold-ijf-approved-white-adult-suit-2021), [Ippon Gear](https://www.ippon-shop.com/en/judo/equipment/judo-uniforms/competitors/512/ippon-gear-ijf-judo-jacket-olympic-slim-fit?number=JJ691SW-145&c=2074#8b03d654bc778d08a79585f9705fc26e) etc all make "regular" and "slim" versions of their IJF Red Label gis (i.e. narrower jacket):

| Brand⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ | Size chart | Height/Weight chart |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adidas (Champion II **Slim**) | [image] | [image] |
| Mizuno (Yusho IJF **Y**) | [image] | [image] |
| Kappa (Atlanta **Slim**) | [image] |  |
| Ippon Gear (Legend **Slim**) | [image] |  |
| Fighting Films (Superstar 750 **Slim Fit**) | [image] |  |

[Kusakura](https://www.kusakurashop.com/products/judogi-jacket-ijf-competition-white-jofc) have more granular sizing for their gis (over 100 cuts), and you can choose your fit based on height, weight, and arm length.